# v.net.steiner tool in QGIS not producing output

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, vector, graph

I have a shapefile of a network of points mostly on roads (a county shapefile from TIGER downloads). I want to find a minimal length tree along the road network that hits all points within 100m of the road. I've tired many different ways of using the v.net.steiner GRASS tool but it doesn't produce any output, saying the layer was not correctly generated. I've tried snapping, using random points instead, changing projection, etc, but always the same result.

Is there anything else I can try? Or is there any other way to approximate a Steiner tree out of two shapefiles?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? If so, please add to your report at https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/1572

Comment: I added it to the link